# A Course in Arithmetic book question on Modular Forms

Tags: number-theory

I have a question on the modular forms section of the book.  It is on the section of lattices.  Jean states, "We can identify the set R of lattices of C with the quotient of M by the action of SL2Z."  Then he defines an action of the complex numbers on R and says "the quotient M/C* is identified with H and the identification transforms the action of SL2Z on M to SL2Z/+-{1} on H" (H is the upper half plane of C and M is a pair of elements in C* where the quotient is not real).  He then says the map (omega 1, omega 2) to (omega 1/omega 2) which is z gives by passing to the quotient, a bijection of R/C* onto H/G

My first question is, what does a quotient group identified with some other group mean?  Like the first part, is it just saying there is an action of SL2Z on M? I know previously, he defined an action of SL2Z on M by sending omega 1 and omega 2 to omega1 prime and omega 2 prime.  So I don't know why he doesn't just put we get an action of SL2Z on M.
Same thing for quotient M/C* is identified with H.

Next,what exactly is going on here? I don't get how he's moving from SL2Z on M to SL2Z / +-{1} on H just from that action of C* on R.
(By the way, +-{1} is the identity matrix and -1* identity matrix)

Comment: $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \setminus \mathbb{H}$ isn't a quotient group, but a set of [orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers). And all the fundamental domains for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \setminus \mathbb{H}$ then become  isomorphic this way. So all you need to see is [that there is a simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane) $U \subset \mathbb{H}$ such that $\mathbb{H}= \displaystyle\bigcup_{\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})} \gamma . U$ where the union is disjoint.

Comment: There is also the topology of $\mathbb{H}$ that is transported on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \setminus \mathbb{H}$, making it a Riemann surface, in the same way that for a rank $2$ lattice $\Lambda$ you get that [$\Lambda \setminus \mathbb{C}$ is a complex torus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain#Hints_at_general_definition)